# $K$-algebra homomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $\mathbb{T}_n(K)$ the set of all triangular matrices, where $K$ is a field. And let $U$ the set of all matrices $\lambda=[\lambda_{ij}]$ in $\mathbb{T}_n(K)$ with $\lambda_{ii}=0$. I want to define a $K$-algebra homomorphism between $\mathbb{T}_n(K)$ and the product of $n$ copies of $K$.

I thought this

$\varphi:\mathbb{T}_n(K)\rightarrow K\times K\cdots\times K$

such that for $A\in\mathbb{T}_n(K)$, $\varphi(A)=(a_{11},a_{22},\ldots, a_{nn})$

But when I try to prove that $\varphi$ is a ring homomorphism I have a problem because: Let $A=[a_{ij}]$ and $B=[b_{ij}]$ then $AB=D=[d_{ij}]$ where $d_{ij}=\sum_{r=1}^na_{ir}b_{rj}$ so

\begin{align*}
\varphi(AB)&=\varphi(D)\\
&=(d_{11},d_{22},\ldots,d_{nn})\\
&=\left(\sum_{r=1}^na_{1r}b_{r1},\sum_{r=1}^na_{2r}b_{r2},\ldots,\sum_{r=1}^na_{nr}b_{rn}\right)
\end{align*}

on the other hand 
\begin{align*}
\varphi(A)\varphi(B)&=(a_{11},a_{22},\ldots, a_{nn})(b_{11},b_{22},\ldots, b_{nn})
\end{align*}

I don't know how to define this product in ordet to $\varphi$ be a ring homomorphism.

Comment: Your $\varphi$ is correct. To show that it's a ring homomorphism you need to make explicit use of the fact that the matrices involved are upper triangular, which you haven't so far.

Comment: Using this fact I would have that $\varphi(AB)=(a_{11}b_{11},\ldots,a_{nn}b_{nn})$, so$ \varphi(A)\varphi(B)=(a_{11}b_{11},\ldots,a_{nn}b_{nn})$?

Answer (score 1):

Note that $X\in\Bbb T_n(K)$ if and only if $[X]_{mn}=0$ for $m>n$.

Then for $A,B\in\Bbb T_n(K)$ we have
\begin{align*}
[AB]_{ii}
&= \sum_{j=1}^n[A]_{ji}[B]_{ij} \\
&= \sum_{j=1}^{i-1}[A]_{ji}\underbrace{[B]_{ij}}_{=0}+\sum_{j=i+1}^n\underbrace{[A]_{ji}}_{=0}[B]_{ij}+[A]_{ii}[B]_{ii} \\
&= [A]_{ii}[B]_{ii}
\end{align*}
Now, your map $\varphi :\Bbb T_n(K)\to K^n$ is $\varphi(X)=([X]_{11},\dotsc,[X]_{nn})$. For $A,B\in \Bbb T_n(K)$ we have
\begin{align*}
\varphi(AB)
&= ([AB]_{11},\dotsc,[AB]_{nn}) \\
&= ([A]_{11}[B]_{11},\dotsc,[A]_{nn}[B]_{nn}) \\
&= ([A]_{11},\dotsc,[A]_{nn})\cdot([B]_{11},\dotsc,[B]_{nn}) \\
&= \varphi(A)\cdot\varphi(B)
\end{align*}
Checking that $\varphi(\lambda A)=\lambda\varphi(A)$ and $\varphi(A+B)=\varphi(A)+\varphi(B)$ is straightforward. Hence $\phi$ is a $K$-algebra homomorphism.